# Bamboo Remote Agent: HTTP 404 on fingerprint request

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

I'm having trouble installing a Bamboo remote agent. I'm running the following command:

```
java -jar ./atlassian-bamboo-agent-installer-4.1.2.jar http://my-domain/agentServer/
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2014/05/22 14:13:58 | JVM exited while starting the application.
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/05/22 14:13:58 | Exiting due to fatal exception.
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/05/22 14:13:58 | com.atlassian.bamboo.agent.bootstrap.RemoteAgentHttpException: HTTP status code 404 received in response to fingerprint request.
```

I've noticed, however, that the URL that the installer is pointing to is incorrect.

```
http://my-domain.com:8085/bamboo/agentServer/GetFingerprint.action?hostName=209.97.200.176&version=3&agentUuid=fb0de79e-a87b-44d3-8a08-5e1fe1278a36
```

There's an extra directory in there that shouldn't be (`/bamboo`), and it doesn't appear that my command line argument affects it. I believe this is the source of my 404 error.

I am running Bamboo 4.2.1; firewall ports are open and network connectivity has been established. I downloaded the JAR from our server. I've seen suggestions for configuration changes to config.xml, but that hasn't been created yet as the remote agent installation hasn't completed.

Has anyone run into this issue before? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly me, I ran into this problem at the beginning of the week, and only now figured out the fix. I grepped for "agentServer" and, as it turns out, there's no config.xml - but there IS a "wrapper.conf" file where the URL is stored. I guess the file is written the first time you run the command; if the command fails, the command argument is ignored in favor of the file configuration.

```
bash-3.2$ grep -R 'agentServer' ./*
./bamboo-agent-home/atlassian-bamboo-agent.log:INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/05/15 08:10:46 | 2014-05-15 08:10:46,374 INFO [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [AgentBootstrap] Agent bootstrap using baseUrl: http://my-domain:8085/bamboo/agentServer/
./bamboo-agent-home/atlassian-bamboo-agent.log:INFO   | jvm 5    | 2014/05/22 14:13:58 | 2014-05-22 14:13:58,252 INFO [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [AgentBootstrap] Agent bootstrap using baseUrl: http://my-domain:8085/bamboo/agentServer/

...

./bamboo-agent-home/conf/wrapper.conf:wrapper.app.parameter.2=http://my-domain:8085/bamboo/agentServer/
```

Changing the offending line in wrapper.conf was the fix. The problem was caused by using the incorrect URL during the first run of the installation.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem, and finally realised that the URL suggested by the [Atlassian documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-remote-agent-installation-guide-289276832.html) was incorrect for my installation. I ended up executing this command (note the lack of the `/bamboo` path segment):

```
java -jar atlassian-bamboo-agent-installer-5.10.3.jar http://bamboo.mydomain.com:8085/agentServer/
```